# Copy/Move files from S3 location to EBS mounted on EC2 via airflow DAG

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a airflow DAG. I want to copy files from S3 location to EBS mounted on EC2 to a specific location say */usr/local/myfiles* via DAG.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UniversalTransferOperator` for this. This is equivalent to transferring files from the S3 bucket to the local. Get started using this [documentation](https://github.com/astronomer/apache-airflow-provider-transfers/tree/main#run-universaltransferoperator-using-astro).

The following should work:

```
import os
import pathlib
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG

from universal_transfer_operator.constants import FileType
from universal_transfer_operator.datasets.file.base import File
from universal_transfer_operator.datasets.table import Metadata, Table
from universal_transfer_operator.universal_transfer_operator import UniversalTransferOperator

CWD = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent
DATA_DIR = str(CWD) + "/../../data/"

with DAG(
    "example_universal_transfer_operator",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
    transfer_non_native_s3_to_ebs = UniversalTransferOperator(
        task_id="transfer_non_native_s3_to_ebs",
        source_dataset=File(path="s3://path/to/file", conn_id="aws_default"),
        destination_dataset=File(
            path=File(path=f"{DATA_DIR}/path/to/destination_file"),
        ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one solution, I'm sure there are other ways.
You can have an `SSHOperator` that will run an `aws cli` command on your EC2 instance.

For example:

```
your_task = SSHOperator(
task_id = "copy_from_s3",
command = "aws s3 cp s3://... /usr/local/myfiles ",
ssh_hook = SSHHook(ssh_conn_id='your_conn'),
dag=dag)
```